# Что прописать в Gradle для push уведомлений?

Tags: java, android

Хотел разобраться с push уведомлениями. Нашел информацию, что нужно в builg.gradle добавить

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0'
```

в app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

туда же

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0"
```

мой app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
.........................
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

красной линией выделяется эта строка

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.

В чем может быть проблема? Может статья устарела и надо прописывать что-то другое?

Comment: вам в Firebase Console нужно создать проект, вбить пекейж, sha ключ, скачать google-services.json и положить его в пакет app

Comment: а вообще а зачем для пушей гугл?

Comment: В статье, которую я нашел, очень подробно описаны все шаги, а то, что вы написали, мне непонятно совсем. Я не из продвинутых.

Comment: Работать с уведомлениями можно и без этих библиотек. Объясните смысл вашей задачи

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с пушами в Андроид есть две системы:

- GCM https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/
- FCM https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

До GCM была еще одна, но это уже совсем давняя история.
На данный момент для новых проектов настойчиво рекомендуется FCM.

Есть отличный официальный туториал, который всегда актуален и написан для нескольких платформ, включая конечно же Андроид.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Вот по нему все и делайте пошагово,там все расписано очень подробно.